# Calcular el diferencial de precio en 1hora

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola tengo la tabla divisas con mas de 200 divisas que agrego mediante una api.

Quisiera saber cuales divisas han aumentado más el diferencial de precio(%) en la ultima hora.

Estoy probando algo tal que así pero no lo veo:

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
    include "db.php";
    
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM divisas");
    $fila = mysqli_num_rows($q);
    
 $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT divisa.* from divisas where divisa.precio = (select max(divisa.precio) from divisas where divisa.divisa = divisa.divisa);
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Y que fue lo que intentaste? y lo intentaste en sql o en php?

Comment: En PHP. No se por donde empezar, seria de gran ayuda cualquier consejo que pudieras darme. gracias por responder

Comment: Empeza haciendolo para una sola moneda.. y fijate a donde te lleva...

Comment: No logro entender lo que quieres. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Hola , cada 30min inserto los campos de divisa y precio en la tabla divisas, y lo que quiero es saber cual moneda aumenta mas su valor cada hora

Comment: @JoseAlvarez tienes que mejorar el planteamiento porque solo estás explicando la mitad de los datos (los almacenados en la base de datos) pero no indicas de donde provienen exactamente los datos con los cuales se está haciendo la comparación y eso es importante. Adicionalmente, deberías describir la estructura de los campos que contienen los datos de la base de datos.

Comment: Cierto. Creo que mejor intentare almacenar los datos cada 30 sg y luego buscar el nombre de las monedas, ordenar las consultas por fechas y sacar el diferencial, graqcias por tu respuesta Juan

Answer (score 0):

Esta query retorna la última cotización de cada divisa incluyendo el porcentaje de variación con respecto a la cotiazación anterior. Las devuelve ordenadas según el porcentaje de variación (de mayor a menor).

Yo agregué la columan fecha, para poder ordenar las cotizaciones por fecha (además de por la hora), no se como haces tu para distinguir las cotizaciones de diferentes díás.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, 
          ROUND(- (1 - precio / lead(precio) OVER (PARTITION BY divisa ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC)) * 100, 2) AS porcentaje_variacion,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY divisa ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC) AS filaNumero
FROM divisas) AS aux
WHERE filaNumero = 1
ORDER BY porcentaje_variacion DESC;
```

Tené en cuenta que siempre usa la última y anteúltima cotización para cada divisa, si no ingresas información actual para una de ellas, usará la última que tiene disponible.

Comment: Que grande!, me servirá. Aunque tambien quiero es poder compararlo con varios minutos, 1,2,3 y 5 min. muchas gracias

Comment: De nada @JoseAlvarez! No me quedó claro como es que quieres compararlo con varios minutos, un ejemplo con datos del reporte resultante que quisieras ayudaría para entender tu requerimiento.

Comment: Si tu tabla tiene muchos registros, te conviene restringir la cantidad de registros con un WHERE en el SELECT mas anidado, trayendo solo los del último día, o la última hora, para que la query se ejecute mas rapido.

Comment: Si gracias, quiero saber el que crezca más en 1, 3, 5 min. He pensado en realizar consultas a la api cada 30 sg, hacer likes para buscar la moneda, ordenarla por fecha y posicionarla asc 
 con el porcentaje de variacion, unpoco liado..

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo? No me queda claro lo que necesitas. Querés comparar la última cotización de cada divisa con las cotizaciones anteriores (calculando la variación de la divisa y cuanto tiempo pasó entre cada cotización)?